# Base does not exist R

Tags: r

I have been trying to perform methylation data analysis, however I am stuck on the first few steps. I am trying to follow the workflow mentioned [here](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/workflows/vignettes/methylationArrayAnalysis/inst/doc/methylationArrayAnalysis.html) and I am unable to read in my files as it gives me an error saying base does not exist.

```
library(methylationArrayAnalysis)
library(knitr)
library(limma)
library(minfi)
library(IlluminaHumanMethylation450kanno.ilmn12.hg19)
library(IlluminaHumanMethylation450kmanifest)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(missMethyl)
library(minfiData)
library(Gviz)
library(DMRcate)
library(stringr)
library(IlluminaHumanMethylationEPICanno.ilm10b4.hg19)
library(conumee)
dataDirectory <- "C:/Users/35389/Desktop/Medullos/All_combined/"
list.files(dataDirectory, recursive = TRUE)
target_EPIC <- read.metharray.sheet("C:/Users/35389/Desktop/Medullos/All_combined/", pattern = "sample_sheet_2.csv") #tried first with dataDirectory then put the link to files again by myself and still the same error of base does not exist
```

> Error in read.metharray.sheet("C:/Users/35389/Desktop/Medullos/All_combined/", : 'base' does not exists

I have been trying to get around this error for a while now.
I tried to read in the methylation files directly using read.methyarray.exp() however, that way, it greatly reduces the dimensions of my data
[image]

I wonder if anyone of you has had any experiences with this and any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Well, the error is pretty clear: The directory `"C:/Users/35389/Desktop/Medullos/All_combined/"` does not exist. The issue might be as simple as that you need to remove the last `/`.

Comment: As roland states, this is an error that occurs because the file does/directory does not exist. It is caused by [this line](https://github.com/hansenlab/minfi/blob/01310378ec3db8eaf9932f4f14aa097745826820/R/read.meth.R#L264) in the source code (`if (!all(file.exists(base))) stop("'base' does not exists")`). So try `file.exists(base)`, and make sure that it returns `TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem! :)